# LPC 1768 CAN bus off error

Tags: embedded, arm, communication, microcontroller, can-bus

I am working with an [LPC1768](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NXP_LPC#LPC1000_series) ARM Cortex M3 microcontroller by NXP ([datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC1769_68_67_66_65_64_63.pdf), [user manual](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10360.pdf)). I would like to test the CAN bus peripheral in the self test mode described in the user manual under the section '16.5.8 CAN controller self-tests', but it doesn't work.

I tried [these NXP examples](http://ics.nxp.com/support/documents/microcontrollers/zip/code.bundle.lpc17xx.keil.zip) described [on the NXP knowledgebase](http://knowledgebase.nxp.com/showthread.php?t=134) and used the NXP example code (can_self_test codes). All pin configurations run OK, and all CAN bus configuration and CAN bus message frames run OK too (controlled one by one). But inside the CAN1_Send func after this step:

```
CANx->CMR = 0x41;
```

the error flag is set. Nonetheless, CAN1_Send returns SUCCESS.

In fact, this error status means 'bus off error'. 'bus off error' means there was a frame error and CAN controller error. I test Data frame and CAN controller. It works.

I use an RS-232 cable for connecting CAN1 and CAN2. For self testing, I use CAN1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that CAN controller, but that behaviour doesn't surprise me.  If you are performing a standalone test, then although you correctly receive the message you sent, because there are no other nodes on the bus, the message will go unacknowledged.  The controller will retry for a while before entering the error states described in sections 6 and 7 of the [CAN spec](http://www.semiconductors.bosch.de/media/pdf/canliteratur/can2spec.pdf)

Comment: thank you for your answer. this is useful for me but i can't see transmit wave at the transmitting pin.

Comment: You can't see the signal on CAN_TX, or on the CAN_H, CAN_L pair?

Comment: Sounds like a pin configuration problem :(  You may have to go over all the pin setup code line by line and compare it to the manual

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here using an LPC1788 and the problem was related with a wrong CPU clock setup. I wrongly setup the CPU to operate at 96 MHz and I (also wrong) consider that CPU was running in 100 MHz. In this scenario the CAN baudrate configuration was inconsistent, and the CAN module failed to transmit any message. Then when I fixed the CPU clock configurations the problem was solved.